# Services not able to connect to Postgresql when Istio Sidecar is enabled in Kubernetes

Tags: istio

I am trying to enable istio sidecar injection with my containers running on kubernetes. The version on istio init container is `proxy_init:1.0.3-gke.0` and of istio proxy is `istio/proxyv2:1.0.3`.

When I have enabled automatic injection in one of my namespace, my container do not create and got the error

```
decurtis.dxp.core.common.api.hibernate.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb4e7fa5.dataSource(&lt;generated&gt;)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:67)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.&lt;init&gt;(PgConnection.java:216)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:406)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:274)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101
```

Comment: Can you provide Pod configuration?

Comment: @mk_sta I am not able to attach pod configuration, it is too long for a comment. Is there any other way to attach the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

The question is where is your Postgresql. If it is outside the cluster, you have to configure access to it from the cluster, see [this blog post](https://preliminary.istio.io/blog/2018/egress-mongo/) about connecting to an external MongoDB instance.

If it is inside the cluster, but does not have the sidecar injected, you should probably [disable mutual TLS to it](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10062#issuecomment-441575769).

Answer (score 1):

There are also 2 possibilities.

1- your application is starting up faster than the sidecar startup. in other words, your app starts before the sidecar be ready. where you can check if (http://localhost:15000 is up) so it's (2/2)

2- you may need to introduce the ***ServiceEntry*** as @Vadim as mentioned.

```
export "PG_HOST" = pg.exmaple.com
export "PG_IP"=$(host $PG_HOST | grep " has address " | cut -d" " -f4)

kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
   name: external-pg-service-entry
spec:
   hosts:
     - $PG_HOST
   addresses:
     - $PG_IP/32
   ports:
     - number: 5432
      name: tcp
      protocol: TCP
   location: MESH_EXTERNAL
   resolution: STATIC
   endpoints:
     - address: $PG_IP
EOF
```